# hash password and verify it with same variable

Tags: php, hash, passwords

i tried to create this register page more secure then i add this code for password

```
$pas_usr = mysqli_real_escape_string($koneksi, $_POST['pas_usr']);
$pas_usr = password_hash($pas_usr, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

the result is in password column is encrypted

then in login page, when i tried to verify it it says wrong password

here's my login page :

```
//memulai session baru
session_start();

//memanggil koneksi
include "koneksi.php";

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$username = stripslashes($username);  
$password = stripslashes($password);  
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($koneksi, $username);  
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($koneksi, $password);  
$hashquery = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE log_usr = '$username'"));
$hash=$hashquery['hash'];

if(password_verify($password, $hash)){

$query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * from user WHERE log_usr='$username'");
$exitCount=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($exitCount==1){
            $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            $id = $data["log_usr"];
            $lvl = $data["sts_usr"];

            if ($lvl=='A')
            {
                $link = 'index.html';
            }
            elseif($lvl='U')
            {
                $link = 'index.php';
            }
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header ("location:$link");
        exit();
    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Username dan Password tidak valid.'); window.location = 'index.php'</script>";
    }
}else{
    echo "<script>alert('Username dan Password tidak valid.'); window.location = 'index.php'</script>";
}
```

Comment: Where is your password_verify() method? please also show the code written on it..

Comment: @PHPGeek [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) is a PHP Function

Comment: are you expecting the user to enter a hashed password? because you put the user input from `$_POST['password']` into `$hash`

Comment: @Memor-X so i need to input hash and plain password separately in database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) matches your plain password against hashed version of your given password while you're checking with plain password in both parameter. [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) works like this:

```
password_verify($plainPassword, $hashedPassword)

<?php
// See the password_hash() example to see where this came from.
$hash = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';

if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
?>
```

Comment: so in database we have column for plain password and hashed password ?

Comment: i mean hashed password must stored in database too right ?

Comment: Actually in database you only need to save hashed version of the password and while you check you should check user submitted plain password against saved hashed using `password_verify`. Best practice is never save plain password in database.

Comment: oh i get it, so that plain password only needed when user submit it on user login then the program compare it with hash who already stored in database with password_verify function ? so i no need stored plain password in database right ?

Comment: Exactly! Happy coding!

Comment: i tried excactly what you suggested, so i delete the plain password on database, change some code on login page, but I dont understand why my password is wrong or more likely the code didnt get the password ?

Comment: i update the code up there, maybe you can check it :)

Comment: my code it worked 100% i just forgot i manually change some data at database.